# ModelBuilder: How to force a specific transformation in the "Project" tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

At 10.7.1, here's the first part of a model I am creating.  Please note that I have parameterized the input and output:

[image]

My problem is within the *Project* tool: I want it to always use the same datum transformation, but I am unable to get that transformation to appear.  When editing the model, I can drop-down the tool's transformation list, but I cannot make the selected transformation "stick" in the transformation box; the box remains blank. Weird, because I can select the desired Output Coordinate System just above.

I think that the problem has to do with the parameterized input, because if I hard-code an input shapefile, the transformation sticks.

[image]

How do I "force" the desired transformation to appear in the model while still allowing parameterized input?

**EDIT:**

For this tool, the input data will *always* be NAD83 (specifically:
NAD_1983_StatePlane_Washington_North_FIPS_4601_Feet

and the output data will *always* be NAD83 HARN (specifically:
NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Washington_South_FIPS_4602_Feet / VCS:NAVD_1988)

When I Project these two manually, Arc offers a variety of transformations.  I always select:

NAD_1983_To_HARN_WA_OR.

This is the transformation that I want to force my tool to use.

Comment: A GeogTran is only necessary if the source GCS is *not* based on NAD83, at which point, the UI will offer all the potential transformations.

Comment: @Vince good point! That's probably the issue.

Comment: Both good comments, thanks.  But in my case I need a transformation.  Please see my edited post.

Comment: Stu you could try creating a model variable and set it to the required transformation and link it to the tool parameter, pretty much as I show in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using ArcMap 10.6. My test scenario is projecting from BNG to WGS84.

I set up the following model and when I set the output coordinate system in the Project tool it auto-selected the transformation for me. I then exposed it as a parameter

[image: Model]

So everything worked for me. The only thing I can think of is does your input dataset have a coordinate system? It would need one for project to even work.

Comment: Your kind efforts really helped.  Although parameterizing the GT works, it unfortunately forces the user to drop-down and select the desired transformation every time the model run - and that transformation value will be the *same every time.*  That's why I'm searching for a way to hard-code that transformation into the model.

Comment: @StuSmith I suspect the Projection tool is doing some sort of internal validation which is causing the drop down to reset and not stay as transformation you have set.